# What does the prefix 'pm' represent when coding in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

```pascal
case iM of
  0: if (pmLower in mode) then begin
    S := S + cLower[1+Random(Length(cLower))];
    Inc(I);
  end;

  1: if (pmUpper in mode) then begin
    S := S + cLower[1+Random(Length(cLower))];
    Inc(I);
  end;
```

Comment: There is an enumerated type `T` and a set type `S = set of T`. `mode` is a variable of type `S` and `pmUpper` is one of the enumeration's constants. The name of the enumeration type probably consists of two words, the first of which starts with "P" and the second with "M". For example, `type TEngineType = (etLegacy, etModern, etExperimental)`. (And in a completely different context, `pmBooks` could also be a `TPopupMenu` used for a book list control, like a `lvBooks: TListView`.)

Comment: It means whatever the person who wrote the code decided it means. You should read the code to find  the declarations of `pmLower` and `pmUpper`. You've provided a few lines totally out of context and expect us to figure out what it means.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see `pmLower` and `pmUpper` are only "names". So pm has no special meaning or affect on the code. Its a name given by the author of the code. You have to look in the declaration what kind variable or component it is.

Comment: They are identifiers. Almost certainly constants in an enumeration abbreviated "PM" (like TPrinterMode or TPaintMode or TProductionMethod). Almost certainly, it isn't a component.

Comment: Seems like [TPasswordMode](https://wiki.nosociety.de/xwiki/coding:delphi:snippets#random_passwort_klasse).